# What language of Service Pack 2 to install on Office 2007 with Language Packs installed?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, service-pack, language-pack

I have Office 2007 in English with one additional language pack istalled (German).

Now I want to install service pack 2 for the Office.

The download page for that service pack [The 2007 Microsoft Office Suite Service Pack 2 (SP2)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B444BF18-79EA-46C6-8A81-9DB49B4AB6E5&displaylang=en) suggest that I choose the language version. But I have two of them at the same time.

What language version of the service pack to download? Or install both of them?

What if I install one-two more language packs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just install the Service pack in English. The service packs are not affected by the additional language packs that are installed.

the service pack installs:

Previously unreleased fixes that were made specifically for this service pack. 
In addition to general product fixes, these fixes include improvements in stability, in performance, and in security.

All the public updates, security updates, cumulative updates, and hotfixes that were released through February 2009.

Source [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953195)

It does not depend on the language packs you have installed.

Comment: Can you explain why SP size for different language versions also differs? If it were the same, the file size should also be the same. Or do I miss something?

Comment: From what I understand it contains everything in the English version with the additional languages bolted on, therefore if this is correct the language versions should be bigger. i have checked this against the German and French versions and they are larger, supporting the theory.

Comment: Actually, I've come to the same conclusion yesterday. Thank you for confirming my theory.

Answer (score 0):

This update came down automatically for me through Windows Update. So

a) as long as you have Windows Update active

and

b) you're including Office in the updates

it will download and install the correct version for your installation.

Comment: I'm not using Windows Update. I'd like to install everything manually. Which one should I get?